# Travelling salesman on a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm

So, i have N nodes, and N-1 edges. Therefore, the graph can be represented as a tree. Now, I need to find the minimum distance it takes to reach every node at least once. N has an upper bound of 10^5.

Is there any way to do this in a reasonable amount of time? There may be a name for this problem, but if so, I can't find it.

I am aware that TSP is NP-complete. However, as this graph is a tree, I was wondering if there was an actual solution to this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're ending where you started, then I think you'll need to cross every edge exactly twice.  If you can end in a different point, then it's more interesting and complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a tree, then a depth-first or breadth-first [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) is a simple way to visit each node.  This is an O(N) operation.

If it doesn't make any difference to you, then use the depth-first traversal as it uses less memory and IMO is easier to implement.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but does this choose the minimal weight path?

Comment: @Ziyao Wei I may have misunderstood the question, but if it's a tree then there's only one path between any two nodes. I figured that he just wanted a tree traversal but didn't know what the terminology was.

Comment: I don't know, but my understanding is that: consider a tree that has a root, and three children for the root, with paths of weight 1, 2, 3. The minimal should be 2 -> 1 -> 1 -> 3, but a traversal could give you 1 -> 3 -> 3 -> 2. Perhaps I misunderstood it somewhere?

Comment: @Ziyao Wei I see, I was only considering the downward path cost, in which case the order doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is isolate cycles within the graph and group them as one giant node. When you do this you should have a directed acyclic graph of groups that are cycles consisting of your nodes. Finding the shortest path reaching every path in a dag is easy to do, so at that point the only thing would be to make sure your end points of each group connect with the correct node in the group you want to traverse to next.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up solving this problem on my own. Basically, the shortest path that visits every tree in the node will traverse every edge twice except for the the path from the origin to the node farthest away from the origin. So, you use a dfs, and store the longest path. 
Here's my code.

```
long long dfs(int a, int b){ //a is the current node, b is the node you reached the current node from.
ll ans=0;
for(int i=0;i<elist[a].size();i++){ //elist is just a vector of all the edges.
    int x=elist[a][i];
    if(x==b) continue;          //this checks to make sure you aren't going straight back to the previous node you visited.
    ans=max(ans,cost[a][i]+dfs(elist[a][i],a)); //ans is the longest distance. Cost is an array of all the edge costs.
}
return ans;
```

}